# Transaction between 2 repositories in nestjs tyoeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

According to you what would be the procedure for making a transaction between 2 repositories?
Example: I would like to make a transaction with my CompanyRepository & UserRepository because a User belongs to a Company. And I want to be sure that it's all or nothing :wink: Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a transaction based on connection and use `EntityManager` inside the transaction:

```
export class DemoService {
  constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {}

  save(userData, companyData): void {
    this.connection.transaction(async (entityManager: EntityManager) => {
      const companyEntityToSave = entityManager.create(CompanyEntity, companyData);
      const userEntityToSave = entityManager.create(UserEntity, userData);
      
      const company = entityManager.save(CompanyEntity, companyEntityToSave);
      const user = entityManager.save(UserEntity, userEntityToSave);

      return await Promise.all([company, user]);
    });
  }
}
```

---

If you want to use repositories:

```
export class DemoService {
  constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {}

  save(): void {
    this.connection.transaction(async (entityManager: EntityManager) => {
      const companyRepository = entityManager.getRepository(CompanyEntity);
      const userRepository = entityManager.getRepository(UserEntity);
      
      // rest code
    });
  }
}
```

Btw, it's not only one way to use transaction with few  entities, that's just one that I've used last time

Comment: @om-pandey was it helpful for you?